# ¿Como agregar librerías a un proyecto java?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Lo que quiero hacer es añadir librerias jar  al proyecto y no añadirlo como ruta , en estos momentos lo añado de esta forma :

`Librerías ->Add JAR/Folder` y selecciono los que necesito , funciona pero como esas librerías están en mi USB cuando lo desconecto me muestra error en mi proyecto indicándome que debo añadir las librerías

Cuando voy a  las `propiedades del proyecto -> Librerias`  me salen las librerías que uso pero con la ruta de mi USB.

Esta es una captura cuando el USB esta conectado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí una captura cuando desconecto el USB :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede decir como añadir librerías de forma correcta?

La idea final es convertir el proyecto en un ejecutable y tengo la duda de que si lo convierto usando rutas el proyecto `.exe` no ejecute correctamente.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es add Libreary no add project

Comment: Puedes hacer lo que te menciona @RaulCacacho . También hay la opción de crear una carpeta **libs** en la raíz del proyecto y usar la opción **Add JAR/Folder**

Comment: @RaulCacacho de esa forma según tengo entendido esas librerías se añaden de Netbeans pero si luego abro el proyecto en otra pc y su Netbeans no tenga la librería funcionara normalmente ?

Comment: **La idea final es convertir el proyecto en un ejecutable y tengo la duda de que si lo convierto usando rutas el proyecto .exe no ejecute correctamente**

Comment: @Luis  Tienes que crear el ejecutable seria dependendiendo de que proyecto creaste si es web .war y si no es  .jar deberia de funcionar las librerias

Comment: @Luis para que esas librerías las tengas disponibles en otras PC, mejor crea una carpeta **_libs_** (o el nombre que gustes) en la raíz del proyecto y agregalas desde ahí. Así ya no tendrás ese inconveniente.

Comment: Cuando crear el ejecutable todas las librerías se empaquetan dentro del .war o .jar. Y ese archivo es un ejecutable que se puede correr en cualquier plataforma que tenga el JRE instalado

Comment: @PatricioBonilla entonces no importa en que carpeta esta igual lo juntara en el instalador del proyecto?

Comment: @Luis correcto. Siempre y cuando ese ejecutable (.jar o .war) se haya generado de una compilación exitosa.

Comment: @PatricioBonilla Gracias por sacarme de dudas ya cree el ejecutador , si gusta puedes poner tus comentarios   como respuesta para poder marcarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay la opción de crear una carpeta ***libs*** en la raíz del proyecto y usar la opción Add JAR/Folder, para agregarlas desde ahí. Esto permite que al momento de crear el ejecutable todas las librerías se empaquetan dentro del *.war* o *.jar.* Y ese archivo es un ejecutable que se puede correr en cualquier plataforma que tenga el **JRE** instalado.

*NOTA: Recuerda que el ejecutable es válido, siempre y cuando ese (.jar o .war) se haya generado de una compilación exitosa.*

Answer (score 0):

Deberias copiar las librerias en tu proyecto. Normalmente en una carpeta "lib" y luego realizar los pasos de Add Jar con la libreria del workspace.

Por otra parte una mejora seria usar algun sistema com "maven" donde referencies las librerias en el fichero POM y estas se descarguen automaticamente desde un repositorio central